# C Outputting array from another function

Tags: c

I am trying to copy the array winner from my function 'enter', so that i am able to just output it on the 'previous' function. When picking the option for the previous option I have gotten nothing outputting. Its only the last function named 'previous' that is not working, but to produce the problem the majority of the code is needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char enter(char names[][20]);
void menu();
void previous(char winner[][8]);

int main()
{
    char names[16][20];
    int i;

    printf("Please enter the names of the players:\n");

        /*Making the user enter 16 times*/
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
    {   
        scanf("%9s", &names[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    /*Clearing Screen*/
    system("cls");

    menu(names);
    return names[16][20];

}
void menu(char names[][20], char winner[][8])
{
    int choice;

    printf("Please select one of the following options:\n\n"
            "Press 1 to enter game  results\n"
            "Press 2 to display the current round\n"
            "Press 3 to display the players advancing to the next round\n"
            "Press 4 to display the previous round\n"
            "Press 5 to exit the program\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        enter(names);
    }

    system("cls");
    if(choice == 3)
    {
        previous(winner);
    }               
}
char enter(char names[][20])
{

    int result;
    int score1;
    int score2;
    int p, c, j, l, i;
    char winner[8][8];  
        system("cls");

        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            printf("\n\n%s vs %s",names[i],names[i+8]);

            score1 = 0;
            score2 = 0;

            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                printf("\n\nEnter game %d results, press 1 if %s won or"
                       " 2 if %s won :\n",(j+1), names[i], names[i+8]);
                scanf("%d", &result);

                if(result == 1)
                {
                    score1++;
                }
                if(result == 2)
                {
                    score2++;
                }

                printf("\n\n1Current score is %d-%d", score1, score2);

                if(score1 == 3)
                {
                    printf("\n\n%s adavances to the next round!",names[i]);
                    strncpy(winner[i], names[i], 10);
                    printf("\n\nPress Enter to Continue");
                    getch();
                    system("cls");
                    break;
                }

                if(score2 == 3)    
                {
                    printf("\n\n%s adavances to the next round!",names[i+8]);
                    strncpy(winner[i], names[i+8], 10);
                    printf("\n\nPress Enter to Continue");
                    getch();
                    system("cls");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        system("cls");
        printf("The players advancing to the next round are:\n\n");

        for(p = 0; p < 8; p++)
        {
            for(c = 0; c < 8; c++)
            {
                printf("%c",winner[p][c]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n\nPress Enter to Continue");
        getch();
        system("cls");
        menu(names, winner);
        return winner[8][8];            
}

void previous(char winner[][8])
{
    int i, j;

        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                printf("%c",winner[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, `fflush()` is only meant to be used for output streams.

Comment: `&names[i]` -> `names[i]`

Comment: Definition: `void menu(char names[][20], char winner[][8])`. Call from `main` is `menu(names);`. The parameters don't match. There is no way this can work.

Comment: I'm not sure that your program needs the menu structure. Your program manages a knockout tournament, where you can logically only go forward to the next round. So your program is sequential. (Your code has other errors: The number of participants n each round in halved, but you use the hard-coded numbers 16 and 8 everywhere.)

Comment: I am going to make a function for each round. Not sure if this is even remotely effiicent as I have just started learning C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data for the array `winner` in your program! At least not when you call it for the first time.

The signature for the menu function is:

```
void menu(char names[][20], char winner[][8]);
```

but you call it from main like this:

```
menu(names);
```

The `winner` parameter is missing. This shouldn't happen, but you have declared a prototype for this function, namely:

```
void menu();
```

Unfortunately, C treats the empty parens as meaning "whatever parameters you pass", not as function that takes no parameters. That means that your function call slips by. The fix is to provide the correct signature for the prototype and also to pass a suitable `winner` array from `main`.

Strangely, your `enter` function provides a local array `winner`. This array will always be a new array when you call `enter`. That's probably not what you want. As is, your program should have one `names` and one `winner` array. (You can pass these arrays around, but you should make sure that tese arrays are consistent. Don't create new arrays when you really want to operate on existing ones.)

You also call your `menu` recursively. That means the you go  ever deeper into the call structure without real benefit. Dont do that; use a loop instead: `do` display the menu `while` the user hasn't chosen "quit". (There are applications for recursive functions, but this isn't one.)

Comment: Thank you! Managed to fix the problem. Although this problem is fixed i saw you mention something about my arrays in 'enter' being local, as this is the last time I need to add/edit anything in this array, would this still be a   problem?

Comment: You must be aware how long your data "lives". When you call `enter` from `menu`, the function forgets about the winner array in `menu` and creates a new, uninitialised array, which you then pass in turn to `menu` again. This may work, because of your recursive structure, but it is more usual to pass an array in and make the function fill it. Such array are created at op level, e.g. in `main` and then passed "down" to other functions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ill research into changing my recursive structure and in turn look at making everything more efficient.